# From Git commit history date wise retrieval of changed files

Tags: git

Assuming this is the git commit history

august 18th 2014 commit - changed files

```
/dir1/subdir1/file5.ext
```

august 17th 2014 commit - changed files

```
/dir1/file4.ext
```

august 16th 2014 commit - changed files

```
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file1.ext
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file2.ext
/dir1/subdir1/file3.ext
```

august 15th 2014 commit - changed files

```
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file1.ext
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file2.ext
```

august 14th 2014 commit - changed files

```
/dir1/file25.ext
```

Is there a git command/option where I can specify to retrieve all changed files from

august 15th to  august 17th and it must retrieve and download only these files

```
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file1.ext
/dir1/subdir1/subdir2/file2.ext
/dir1/subdir1/file3.ext
/dir1/file4.ext
```

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: `git cherry-pick <hash>` doesn't do?

Comment: You would need to know the commit-ids ?

Comment: Yes, but that's readily available through any number of methods.

Comment: why you say " retrieve and download "? , it sounds subversion... in git your repository must have retrieved all data first

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff --name-only <SHA1> <SHA2>
```

shows differences betwenn commits   (only filenames, [reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))

Also, you can refer to commits by dates using @\{YYYY-MM-DD\} (and other formats, [reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions))

So, to show files changed "from 15 to 17 of August" you can write:

```
git diff --name-only @\{2014-08-15\} @\{2014-08-17\}
```

---

Notes:

- to be precise, the reference says \{date\}) specifies the value of the ref at a prior point in time
- You can also look at

  git whatchanged --since="2014-08-15" --until="2014-08-17"

  but it returns the list of commits, where git diff returns the modifications between the to commits.